# jQuery in .net validate dropdownlist, fadein and fadeout panels

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a dropdownlist control ddlAffilation, a panel pnlForms, a panel Complete, a button Submit, a button Return.

I have a validationcontrol on the dropdownlist.

here is my jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%= Submit.ClientID %>").click(function () {
        $("#<%= pnlForms.ClientID %>").fadeOut('slow');
        $("#Complete").delay(800).fadeIn('slow');

    });
    $("#<%= Return.ClientID %>").click(function () {
        $("#Complete").fadeOut('slow');
        $("#<%= pnlForms.ClientID %>").delay(800).fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
</script>
```

I have 2 problems:
1) With this jQuery code, I can go back and forth (fade out pnlForms, fade in Complete when click on Submit and vice versa when click on Return) only when i don't choose any value in the dropdownlist box. If I choose any value in the dropdownlist, the Return button doesn't work.

2) The jquery code bypass the .net server validation control. I need the code not do anything if no value is selected from the dropdownlist. I have tried

```
var isValid = true;
if ($("#<%= ddlAffilation.ClientID %>").val() == "") {
    isValid = false;
    return false;
}

if (isValid == true) {
...
```

but it doesn't work. What's the best way to do this?

Thanks,

==================================================================================

I can't add an answer to my own question so I reply to John here:

Thanks John. I have my code like this and it solves problem 2.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= Submit.ClientID %>").click(function (e) {
            if (IsValid() == false) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $("#<%= pnlForms.ClientID %>").fadeOut('slow');
                $("#Complete").delay(800).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        }); 
        $("#<%= Return.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            alert('blah2');
            $("#Complete").fadeOut('slow');
            $("#<%= pnlForms.ClientID %>").delay(800).fadeIn('slow');
        });
        function IsValid() {
            // Add any other validation in here
            if ($("#<%= ddlAffilation.ClientID %>").val() == "") {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
</script>
```

However, problem 1 still exists. Let me clarify. I have a few textboxes, a dropdownlist and a submit button to collect feedback from the users. They are all in the panel pnlForms.

All controls can be empty except for the dropdownlist. We took care of this using your code and a server validation control.

when the users click the submit button, I want the pnlForms to fadeOut and a hidden panel called pnlComplete to fadeIn. The pnlComplete has a text saying thanks for the feedback and a button called Return that let the users send another feedback.

When the users click on the Return button, the opposite happens here. The pnlComplete fadeOut and the pnlForms fadeIn.

The Submit button works well but the Return button doesn't work at all. I set some alert() inside the Return.click(function but it doesn't hit.

Any ideas?

---

Here is the code of the whole page.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" 
    AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="content" runat="Server">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlForms" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Your Information</legend>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <label for="ctl00_content_name">
                                Your Name:</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <em class="optional">Optional </em></li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="ctl00_content_status">
                                Your Affiliation:*</label>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAffilation" runat="server" Width="155px">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="--Select One--" Value="" Selected="True" />
                                <asp:ListItem>F</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>S</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>T</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <em class="required">Required
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage=" - Please select your affiliation"
                                    ControlToValidate="ddlAffilation" SetFocusOnError="True" ForeColor=""></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </em></li>
                    </ol>
                </fieldset>
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submit_Click" /></div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <div id="Complete" style="display: none;">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlComplete" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>               
                    <p>Thank you</p>
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <asp:Button ID="Return" runat="server" Text="Return" /></div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpClientScript">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%= Submit.ClientID %>").click(function (e) {
                if (IsValid() == false) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    $("#<%= pnlForms.ClientID %>").fadeOut('slow');
                    $("#Complete").delay(800).fadeIn('slow');
                }
            });
            $("#<%= Return.ClientID %>").click(function () {
                $("#Complete").fadeOut('slow');
                $("#<%= pnlForms.ClientID %>").delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
            });
            function IsValid() {
                // Add any other validation in here
                if ($("#<%= ddlAffilation.ClientID %>").val() == "") {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: can you add rendered output for Return button?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I read your question right or not, but if your issue is that you don't want the jquery to continue firing and allow the form to submit if the dropdown is empty do this:

Instead of attaching a `.click` event to your button, attach a `.submit` event to your form. Then you want to use `e.PreventDefault()` to stop the main submit execution if its not valid

Eg:

```
$("#FORMNAME").submit(function(e) {
    if (IsValid() == false) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    // Submitting form...
}


function IsValid() {
    // Add any other validation in here
    if ($("#<%= ddlAffilation.ClientID %>").val() == "") {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also, you should ALWAYS do server validation along with your client validation.. otherwise all someone has to do is directly submit / bypass your javascript checks

Edit for your edit:
Is the return button being created dynamically or is it there on page load? If its dynamic, its probably never getting assigned to in your jquery, as it doesn't exist when it runs.

Here is a quick test you could try:

```
var returnButton = $("#<%= Return.ClientID %>");
alert(returnButton.attr("id");
```

If you don't get back the ID of your return button, its not matching up in your code and thats why your click event isn't working. If thats the case, do a view source on your page and find out what the actual return button ID is set to (this is easier with **FireBug** or similar tool)

Comment: I added some more for your edit, it sounds like the return button ID is either different than you think, or its not wiring it up in JQuery for some reason (dynamically created after js runs?)

Comment: i got back the ID of the return button when the page first load but I did not after clicking the Submit button (that is when the Return button fadeIn)

Comment: <div id="Complete" style="display: none;">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlComplete" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <p>
                    Thank you
                <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="Return" runat="server" Text="Return" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>

Comment: If you move the return button to a different location so its visible at the start, does it fire off its alert event? If so, something must be modifying it or causing a bug in javascript to not run further events after the submit button events fires. Try adding a third button thats always visible with a basic click -> alert and run it 3 times, 2x before clicking submit and 1 time after. See if all 3 fire (2x before just to make sure it will fire multiple times)

Comment: it's weird that if i get rid of the dropdown validation client code and not select anything from the dropdownlist, the return button works. If I select an item from the dropdownlist, it doesnt work :-/

Comment: Is your code an exact copy/paste of above? If not could you paste in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as a separate answer since its just a huge chunk of code that isn't exactly related to the original answer, but does work as intended. I took the code you gave and converted to basic html from asp.net, and it does work correct, does it work for you?

Could you try posting the output from the asp.net page instead of the code itself? Maybe something isn't being set right on the button element's ID.

```
<html>
<head>

 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ID="Content1">
        <div ID="pnlForms">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Your Information</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <label for="ctl00_content_name">
                            Your Name:</label>
                        <textbox ID="Name" runat="server" Width="150px"></TextBox>
                        <em class="optional">Optional </em></li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="ctl00_content_status">
                            Your Affiliation:*</label>
                        <select ID="ddlAffilation" Width="155px">
                            <option Value="" Selected="True">--Select One--</option>
                            <option>F</option>
                            <option>S</option>
                            <option>T</option>
                        </select
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </fieldset>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
            <Button ID="Submit" Value="Submit" OnClick="submit_Click">Submit</Button></div>
        </div>
    <div id="Complete" style="display: none;">
        <div ID="pnlComplete">          
            <p>Thank you</p>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
            <Button ID="Return" Value="Return">Return</Button></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div ID="Content3">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Submit").click(function (e) {
                if (IsValid() == false) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    $("#pnlForms").fadeOut('slow');
                    $("#Complete").delay(800).fadeIn('slow');
                }
            });
            $("#Return").click(function () {
                $("#Complete").fadeOut('slow');
                $("#pnlForms").delay(1000).fadeIn('slow');
            });
            function IsValid() {
                // Add any other validation in here
                if ($("#ddlAffilation").val() == "") {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```